# How to find a set of three or more number?

Tags: arrays, vba, algorithm, integer

Can you please help me find a set of three numbers og more with a sum of X in a given list.

Fx a set of tree numbers with a sum of 6 in the list 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 would be 1+2+3

I can do this with a set of two numbers se VBA code below

```
Function Set(list As Range, x As Integer)
  k = 0
  j = 0
  For Each i In list
    If x = list(1 + k) + list(list.Rows.Count - j) Then
      Set = k & ", " & j 
    ElseIf list(1 + k) + list(list.Rows.Count - j) > x Then
      j = j + 1
    ElseIf list(1 + k) + list(list.Rows.Count - j) < x Then
      k = k + 1
    End If
  Next i
End Function
```

Best regards
Kresten

Comment: `pair of three numbers` what is this?

Comment: [9,12,200] is a pair of three numbers

Comment: @Kresten in English 'pair' always describes precisely **two** items. A more generic term would be tuple, or set (if order doesn't matter, as in your example).

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

```
Function myPair(list As Range, x As Integer)
    Dim vDB, vR(1 To 3)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Long
    vDB = list
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = i + 1 To n
            For k = j + 1 To n
                If vDB(i, 1) + vDB(j, 1) + vDB(k, 1) = x Then
                    vR(1) = vDB(i, 1): vR(2) = vDB(j, 1): vR(3) = vDB(k, 1)
                    myPair = Join(vR, ",")
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks.

Comment: This certainly works in `O(n^3)` time, but you can do asymptotically better: Use a table lookup to see if `If vDB(i, 1) + vDB(j, 1) ` matches `x - vDB(k, 1) ` for some integer `k`.  This requires pre-processing `x - vDB(k, 1) ` for `k=1` to `n` into a table prior to starting the loops.